# Recursive Expressjs Routing

Tags: node.js, recursion, express

Without resorting to regular expression is there anyway with expressjs to recursively call routing ie url examples:

```
/f:forum/s:section/t:thread/p:post  
/f:forum/s:section/s:section/t:thread/p:post  
/f:forum/s:section/s:section/s:section/t:thread/p:post  
...
```

Therefore allowing technically an infinite amount of "sections/subsections" in the forum.

I attempted to do:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
app.route('/').get(function(req, res, next){
    return res.send('hello');
});
app.use('/f:forum', require('./section'));
server = app.listen(process.env.http || process.env.PORT);
module.exports = app;
```

section.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router = router;
router.route('/s:section').get(function(req, res, next){
  return res.send(req.params);
});
router.use('/s:section', require('./thread'));
module.exports = router;
```

thread.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.use('/s:section', require('./section'));
router.route('/t:thread/p-:post').get(function(req, res, next){
  return res.send(req.params);
});
router.route('/t:thread').get(function(req, res, next){
  return res.send(req.params);
});
module.exports = router;
```

but interestingly it tells me that in thread.js `require('./section') = {}`
yet in app.js it is correct... any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do wildcard routing like `router.route('/:path*')` and then have the handler parse from that point down.

For example, something like:

```
router.route('/forum/:path*', function(req,res){
   var requestPath = req.path; // will present the whole path to you for parsing
   // do whatever db lookup logic you normally would do now that you have the pieces you wanted
   res.render('forum', data);
};
```

Comment: Could you please demonstrate a little of the handler parse part. (Enough so I get the jist of what you mean)